# Story about a person invited to join council of intellects

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a story about a man, maybe a scientist, whose remarkable intellectual achievements earned him an invitation to join the Council of Intellects, which was considered to be a great honor.  When he had a chance to enter the hall of the Council, however, he was shocked to find it consisted of brains in jars connected to each other by wires, realizing this would be his fate as well.  So in the end he decided to just run away.  Anyone recall the title of the story?  I may have read it in the early 1980s when I was in junior high school.  It may have been in a publication for young readers such as from Scholastic.

Answer (score 16):

This is "All the Colors of the Vacuum" by Charles Sheffield. "The Compleat McAndrew" contains the story. It's [been published a few times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49539) since its original appearance in *Analog* in 1981.

> But the Council of Intellects was well-named. After someone has been pared down, flesh, bone and organs, to a brain and a spinal column, intellect is all that can remain. Perhaps the thing that upset me more than anything in that inner room was their decision to leave the eyes intact. They were there, attached to each brain by the protruding stalks of their optic nerves. They looked like the horns of a snail, blue, grey or brown balls projecting from the frontal lobes. Since there were no muscles left to change the focal length of the eye lenses, they were directed to display screens set at fixed distances from the tanks.

Comment: @Jenayah I tossed up whether or not to include the (probably illegal) link to the story. Happy for you to have taken it out.

Comment: No worries, if anyone wants to look it up they're free to Google the exact quotes on their own ;)

Comment: Thanks. This helps me locate the story so I can read it again.

Comment: @moebius glad to help. Please tick the answer as correct so anyone else looking for the story can be certain it's it.

Comment: I think I’d like to read the story first to make sure it’s the right one.

Comment: I've read the story in Analog.  It's not quite the story I remember.  The part about the Council of Intellects is definitely something I remember, but I don't remember the parts about the asteroid or the physics theories, or the female astronaut named Jeanie.  I must have seen a truncated version in a magazine for young readers published by Scholastic under a series title called "This is the Future" about future trends and including various stories about the future.